# Multi-module gradle project. Problem with import

Tags: java, gradle, microservices, spring-cloud

I have project with microservice architecture.
I am trying to import one of my modules(#1) to another module(#2) of my project to use classes of module#1 in module#2.

---

I tried to add dependecy in module#2 to add module#1 in it like this(last lines in dependencies):

[image: dependencies image]

I have all includeBuild in my outer project(that includes all modules).

[image: includeBuilds Image]

And anyway I have this error:

```
users-service:test: Could not find ru.micro:entities:.
Required by:
    project :
```

[image: Error image]

How is it possible to use classes of one module in another module of project using gradle?

I tried to add one module to another by adding dependencies(like on screenshots) but it didn't work.

Comment: remove line 38 (i.e. import as library) and uncomment line 39 `implementation project(':entities')` see if this works

Comment: the same issue
A problem occurred evaluating project ':users-service'.
> Project with path ':entities' could not be found in project ':users-service'.

Comment: In settings.gradle instead of `includeBuild` try only `include`. Thats the only difference I see from my multi module setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in gradle hierarchy.
When you create a module with spring boot initializr gradle add this module not in parent project but independently like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn8Sr.png).
You have to delete this gradle config and add include 'someModuleName' in your root settings.gradle. then you will have picture like this [the proper gradle tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iP2o.png)

Answer (score 1):

In a multimodule repository, when you are importing one project repository into another project in the same repository,

u need to use implementation project for importing dependencies.

for example, if Repository A contains x and y projects and I need to use x dependency in y, then I need to use

```java
implementation project(':dependency_used_in_x')
```

also one more scenario where x and y projects are present in an independent repository, then you need to use implementation for importing dependencies.

```java
implementation('com.package:dependency_used_in_x)
```

I'm coming to your answer

It must be

```java
implementation project(':entities')
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Have the same issue
A problem occurred evaluating project ':users-service'.
> Project with path ':entities' could not be found in project ':users-service'.